# Hibernate 'ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()' but mapped data contains the id already

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data Rest, Hibernate ORM, and PostgreSQL.

I am receiving uploaded spreadsheet with data from `/upload` route and mapping it to `Product.class`.
When the spreadsheet is processed and mapped to my `Product.class` and I pass the `Product.class` to `productRepo.save(product)` I receive this error message

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
```

`Product.class` is created with these annotations

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="prd")
public class Product {

@Id
private Integer nbrSupCmbndKey;
```

`nbr_sup_cmbnd_key` is the primary key column in the db and this data is being provided to me through the upload( I do not need to auto generate this field)

how do I configure hibernate so that it saves properly because this information is already contained in the mapped `Product.class` when I go to do a `productRepo.save(Product)`?